# Duplicate Classnames after installing iCalendar gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, icalendar

I just tried to deal with iCalendar gem, but it seems iCalendar has a class named `Event`, and my app also have a class named `Event`

I guess there is a way to scope one or another class name, but i just don't know how.

Here's an example of what i'd like to do :

`Event.new` => ActiveRecord Model

`Icalendar::Event.new` => Icalendar Event class

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoe about wrapping up the `iCalendar` gem in a module and then instantiating from e.g. `Icalendar::CalEvent` or something?

```
require 'icalendar'

module Icalendar
  CalEvent = Event
end
```

BTW: you could just use the name `Event`, but there will be a warning about reassigning to a constant.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. I can now access my AR Model via `Event` and iCalendar class via `Icalendar::Event`, just like i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Force ruby to look for top-level class definitions when accessing your model, via `::Event.new`. Including :: before class name signifies that class is not in any module, as opposed to `Icalendar::Event` that is in `Icalendar` module.

Or, if iCalendar does not provide the namespace, you can do it for your class, defining it as

```
module MyStuff
  class Event
  end
end
```

and using `MyStuff::Event` for your model, and `::Event` for iCal one.